# DB table creation -- breaking down age groups

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I have a tutoring website where teachers list their preferences for the ages of their potential students.

So far, I have broken those ages into the following categories:
0-4, 5-9, 10-14, 15-19, Adults. These categories, I think, represent decent break points for students ages. But no matter -- the real issue is table creation.

I will make a secondary table, teachers_ages, with a foreign key for teacher_id and another column for age. Should I make this column an enum, with the following acceptable choices '0-4' '5-9', '10-14', '15-19', 'Adults'?. Is this somehow bad-practice (to group numbers with words?) Does it violate any database creation norms? Is there a better way to break age groups for use with CRUD?

Update: teachers can choose as many age groups as they want

Comment: 0? Yep, guess there's no sense hanging around when it comes to education

Comment: You've really got two options, the first is (as you mentioned) to use an ENUM field with each age group defined which is fine, even with the "Adults" option.  But what I'd probably do instead is create an age_groups table with each group in a separate row which can be referenced via a foreign key from the teacher table.  The benefit to doing this is that you could always develop an easy interface for adding, removing and editing age groups so administrators have flexibility.  Also, I wouldn't classify "15-19" as numeric anyway, as it has a dash, making it no different to "Adults."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you would create a lookup table which would list an identifier and the associated value.  For example

Lookup table (AgeRange)

```
ID     Min_Age   Max_Age   Description
1      0         4         "Less than 4"
2      5         9         "5 to 9"
3      10        14        "10 to 14"
4      15        19        "15 to 19"
5      20        1000      "Adults"
```

Now you can add another table with the teacher id and the age range id.  (There can be more than one entry in this table allowing teachers to have any number of preferences.)

When validating you join to this table and look at Min_Age and Max_Age.  When reporting you use the Description field.

Answer (score 0):

If each teacher can only choose one age group you do not need to add a second table. Put the age-group field in the teacher table. Set the datatype as varchar and use check constraints for your five choices.

Your approach is a valid way to break groups down into demographics, such as age, income, population, etc.

Comment: NOTE: MySQL doesn't enforce CHECK constraints. MySQL does accept the syntax but the constraint isn't ever enforced. (As to why MySQL accepts the syntax, its probably either for improved compatibility with DDL imported from another database, and for documentation. It's possible to define trigger to emulate a CHECK constraint.